# Delete files with root ownership in Vala

Tags: root, delete-file, vala, owner

I need to **delete files** from the **cache** of **APT** and with the functions of files that Vala provides not let me.

Someone who can give me a hand?

The code is the following:

```
//Compile it using: valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg gio-2.0 del-apt-cache.vala
using Gtk;
using GLib;

private int64[] get_info_and_clean (File file, string space = "",  Cancellable? cancellable = null) throws Error
{
    int64 files = 0;
    int64 size  = 0;
    int64[] data = new int64[2];

    Array<string> paths = new Array<string> ();

    FileInfo info = null;
    FileEnumerator enumerator;

    try {//This Try/Catch is to ignore the permissions of '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial'
        enumerator = file.enumerate_children (
            "standard::*",
            FileQueryInfoFlags.NOFOLLOW_SYMLINKS, 
            cancellable);
    } catch (IOError e) {
        stderr.printf ("WARNING: Unable to get size of dir '%s': %s\n", file.get_path (), e.message);
        data[0] = 0;
        data[1] = 0;
        return data;
    }

    while (cancellable.is_cancelled () == false && ((info = enumerator.next_file (cancellable)) != null)) {
        if (info.get_file_type () == FileType.DIRECTORY) {
            File subdir = file.resolve_relative_path (info.get_name ());
            get_info_and_clean (subdir, space + " ", cancellable);
        } else {
            files += 1;//Sum Files
            size  += info.get_size ();//Accumulates Size
            paths.append_val (file.get_uri () + "/" + info.get_name ());
        }
    }

    if (cancellable.is_cancelled ()) {
        throw new IOError.CANCELLED ("Operation was cancelled");
    }

    data[0] = files;
    data[1] = size;

    File apt_file;

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        apt_file = File.new_for_uri (paths.index (i));
        stdout.printf ("FILE:  %s", paths.index (i));
        try {
            apt_file.delete ();
            stdout.printf (" [DELETED]\n");
        } catch (Error e) {
            stdout.printf (" [ERROR: %s]\n\n", e.message);
        }
    }

    stdout.printf ("APT CACHE FILES: %s\n", files.to_string());
    stdout.printf ("APT CACHE SIZE: %s\n", size.to_string());

    return data;
}

public static int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    File APT_CACHE_PATH = File.new_for_path ("/var/cache/apt/archives");
    try {
        get_info_and_clean (APT_CACHE_PATH, "", new Cancellable ());
    } catch (Error e) {
        stdout.printf ("ERROR: %s\n", e.message);    
    }

    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

> FILE:  file:///var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-1-3_1.10.6-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb [ERROR: Failed to delete file: Permission denied]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing Vala can do if the operating system is denying you permission. You need to run your Vala program as root either using `sudo` or setting the “setuid” bit on the application and changing the owner to root.

Comment: In addition the app could use a mechanism like `PolicyKit` or `gksu` to run a `rm` job with elevated privileges.